# nohup.out file created as empty

Tags: solaris-10

I'm trying to create the thread dump of the java process and for that i'm using nohup kill -3  command. In that case nohup.out file is created but it's empty. Even i tried redirecting the file to some other locations and even the created file is also empty.

Can anybody please help me out?

Thanks
Ram

Comment: Are you running from the terminal or from the crontab? And which shell type are you using: csh, ksh, bash, ...?

Comment: thanks for your response quanta. I'm running the script from terminal and the shell type is ksh. Even i tried using the jstack tool comes along with jdk 1.5 and even that didn't help me much

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking in the wrong place. Think of the `kill -3` command as not producing a thread dump itself but as telling your java application to do so.

So check its log files, and its working directory (use pwdx command to find that).

Comment: Hi ramruma, I guess i'm looking at the right place. Just to verify i have used the pwdx as per you advise and it generates the nohup.out file but then it's empty again

Comment: Do not use nohup. Is this java application writing to its own log files? If so, look in there. Use pwdx on the java app to find its working directory.

Comment: kill -3 <pid> command doesn't create any logs in the running application and i'm pretty sure that kill -3 is the basic command and which will work to get the thread dumps in all the Java version. It's so strange Ramruma. isn't it? And as i said earlier i redirected the kill -3 <pid> to some other location like 'kill -3 9612 > /opt/webmethods/7.1.2/PPT01a/threaddumps.txt
' and it creates the file named 'threaddumps.txt' in the path given but then it's empty again.

Comment: You are redirecting the output of the kill command but the kill command just sends a signal to your java app. You need to find where java is writing.